# How to block presta for unregistered users?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How can I disable access to presta for unregistered users (b2b solution)? After registration I want to user account must be accepted by the administrator? How can i make this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your visitors are logged in or not and redirect to authentication page.
To be able to accept new registrations, you can use some hook that triggers just after new account creation and disable the account to accept later from backoffice.